# stuck in my homework to prove or disprove h(f(n)) = O (h(g(n)))

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I understand big-oh and theta. the question is as follows,
prove or disprove: f(n) = theta(g(n) => h(f(n)) = O(h(g(n))) if h(n) is an increasing function. h(n1) > h(n2) when n1 > n2

So, in the above question, I am stuck at the point of understanding the increasing function. If I am trying to find some function to disprove it, say eg., n and 2n is this acceptable? becos big-oh represents rapidly growing and not just by a constant factor, but there is no such condition with h(n) function defined (I mean, I consider > as literally greater than here, is that wrong?)

Also, even if I find something like h(f(n)) growing at the same rate as h(g(n)) which means they are theta essentially, are they still big-oh. becos loose bound of theta is big-oh in that case, I can never disprove the above statement.

Please correct me if I my understanding deviated at some point while going thru the sequence. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a contradictory example to solve this problem, by taking `f(n) = 2n` and `g(n) = n` which satisfies the given `f(n) = theta(g(n))`.

Now, let `h(x) = 2^x`, this implies that `h(f(n)) = 2^2n = 4^n` and `h(g(n)) = 2^n`.

By definition, this means that `h(g(n)) = O(h(f(n)))`. Hence disproved.

I never knew that contradictory examples were sufficient for disproving. I was trying a more formal way to prove it and was getting messed up with details.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I always start problems like this by re-reading and then writing down the definitions of Theta(f) and O(f). If you can find a simple example which disproves the assertion, you won't have to prove anything. I like the idea of very rapidly growing h(x) such as h(x) = 2^x. Then if you have e.g. f(x) = 2x, g(x) = x, h(f(x)) = 2^(2x), h(g(x)) = 2^x and h(f(x)) / h(g(x)) = 2^x - try pluging these into your definitions and see what happens. Notice that, since f(x) = 2g(x), at least by my definition, you have f(x) = Theta(g(x)) and g(x) = Theta(f(x))